Small performance gain using AVX512 over SSE in batch quaternion-vector multiplication
I've implemented a quaternion-vector multiplication function using SIMD instructions, with conditional compilation for AVX512, AVX2, and SSE. While I expected to see significant performance improvements with newer instruction sets (AVX512 > AVX2 > SSE), the actual performance difference is surprisingly small.
The result of
for f in "-mno-avx -mfma sse" "-mavx -mavx2 -mfma avx" "-mavx512f -mfma mavx512"; do
    g++ -O3 -w quat_vec_mult.cpp -I/usr/include/eigen3 -std=c++20 ${f% *}
    echo "${f##* }"
    ./a.out
done

is
sse
Time: 104786 us
Sum: -3309.12
avx
Time: 100155 us
Sum: -3309.12
mavx512
Time: 98113 us
Sum: -3309.12

My questions are two-holds

Why might the performance difference between AVX512, AVX2, and SSE be so small in this case?
Could there be any bottlenecks in my implementation that are limiting the potential speedup from more advanced SIMD instructions?

Note that my cpu spec is https://gist.github.com/HiroIshida/7230aab2d40a6cae7b18c552a363f31f
The below is the code
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>
#include <random>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <fstream>

#ifdef __AVX512F__
  const size_t bytes_alligned = 64;
  const size_t n_batch = 8;
#define SIMD_LOAD _mm512_load_pd
#define SIMD_STORE _mm512_store_pd
#define SIMD_ADD _mm512_add_pd
#define SIMD_SUB _mm512_sub_pd
#define SIMD_MUL _mm512_mul_pd
#define SIMD_SET1 _mm512_set1_pd

#elif __AVX2__ 
  const size_t bytes_alligned = 32;
  const size_t n_batch = 4;
#define SIMD_LOAD _mm256_load_pd
#define SIMD_STORE _mm256_store_pd
#define SIMD_ADD _mm256_add_pd
#define SIMD_SUB _mm256_sub_pd
#define SIMD_MUL _mm256_mul_pd
#define SIMD_SET1 _mm256_set1_pd

#else
  const size_t bytes_alligned = 16;
  const size_t n_batch = 2;
#define SIMD_LOAD _mm_load_pd
#define SIMD_STORE _mm_store_pd
#define SIMD_ADD _mm_add_pd
#define SIMD_SUB _mm_sub_pd
#define SIMD_MUL _mm_mul_pd
#define SIMD_SET1 _mm_set1_pd
#endif

void quat_mult_vec(
    double* qx, double* qy, double* qz, double* qw,
    double* x, double* y, double* z,
    double* output_x, double* output_y, double* output_z){
  auto qx_vec = SIMD_LOAD(qx);
  auto qy_vec = SIMD_LOAD(qy);
  auto qz_vec = SIMD_LOAD(qz);
  auto qw_vec = SIMD_LOAD(qw);
  auto x_vec = SIMD_LOAD(x);
  auto y_vec = SIMD_LOAD(y);
  auto z_vec = SIMD_LOAD(z);
  auto ones = SIMD_SET1(1);
  auto twos = SIMD_SET1(2);

  auto qxqx_2 = SIMD_MUL(SIMD_MUL(qx_vec, qx_vec), twos);
  auto qyqy_2 = SIMD_MUL(SIMD_MUL(qy_vec, qy_vec), twos);
  auto qzqz_2 = SIMD_MUL(SIMD_MUL(qz_vec, qz_vec), twos);
  auto qwqw_2 = SIMD_MUL(SIMD_MUL(qw_vec, qw_vec), twos);
  auto qxqy_2 = SIMD_MUL(SIMD_MUL(qx_vec, qy_vec), twos);
  auto qxqz_2 = SIMD_MUL(SIMD_MUL(qx_vec, qz_vec), twos);
  auto qxqw_2 = SIMD_MUL(SIMD_MUL(qx_vec, qw_vec), twos);
  auto qyqz_2 = SIMD_MUL(SIMD_MUL(qy_vec, qz_vec), twos);
  auto qyqw_2 = SIMD_MUL(SIMD_MUL(qy_vec, qw_vec), twos);
  auto qzqw_2 = SIMD_MUL(SIMD_MUL(qz_vec, qw_vec), twos);

  auto M00 = SIMD_SUB(SIMD_ADD(qwqw_2, qxqx_2), ones);
  auto M01 = SIMD_SUB(qxqy_2, qzqw_2);
  auto M02 = SIMD_ADD(qxqz_2, qyqw_2);
  auto output_x_vec = SIMD_ADD(SIMD_ADD(SIMD_MUL(M00, x_vec), SIMD_MUL(M01, y_vec)), SIMD_MUL(M02, z_vec));
  SIMD_STORE(output_x, output_x_vec);

  auto M10 = SIMD_ADD(qxqy_2, qzqw_2);
  auto M11 = SIMD_SUB(SIMD_ADD(qwqw_2, qyqy_2), ones);
  auto M12 = SIMD_SUB(qyqz_2, qxqw_2);
  auto output_y_vec = SIMD_ADD(SIMD_ADD(SIMD_MUL(M10, x_vec), SIMD_MUL(M11, y_vec)), SIMD_MUL(M12, z_vec));
  SIMD_STORE(output_y, output_y_vec);

  auto M20 = SIMD_SUB(qxqz_2, qyqw_2);
  auto M21 = SIMD_ADD(qyqz_2, qxqw_2);
  auto M22 = SIMD_SUB(SIMD_ADD(qwqw_2, qzqz_2), ones);
  auto output_z_vec = SIMD_ADD(SIMD_ADD(SIMD_MUL(M20, x_vec), SIMD_MUL(M21, y_vec)), SIMD_MUL(M22, z_vec));
  SIMD_STORE(output_z, output_z_vec);
}


int main(){
  size_t N = 10000000;
  size_t aligned_N = N + (n_batch - N % n_batch);

  double* qx = static_cast<double*>(aligned_alloc(bytes_alligned, aligned_N * sizeof(double)));
  double* qy = static_cast<double*>(aligned_alloc(bytes_alligned, aligned_N * sizeof(double)));
  double* qz = static_cast<double*>(aligned_alloc(bytes_alligned, aligned_N * sizeof(double)));
  double* qw = static_cast<double*>(aligned_alloc(bytes_alligned, aligned_N * sizeof(double)));
  double* x = static_cast<double*>(aligned_alloc(bytes_alligned, aligned_N * sizeof(double)));
  double* y = static_cast<double*>(aligned_alloc(bytes_alligned, aligned_N * sizeof(double)));
  double* z = static_cast<double*>(aligned_alloc(bytes_alligned, aligned_N * sizeof(double)));
  double* output_x = static_cast<double*>(aligned_alloc(bytes_alligned, aligned_N * sizeof(double)));
  double* output_y = static_cast<double*>(aligned_alloc(bytes_alligned, aligned_N * sizeof(double)));
  double* output_z = static_cast<double*>(aligned_alloc(bytes_alligned, aligned_N * sizeof(double)));

  for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    Eigen::Vector4d q = Eigen::Vector4d::Random();
    Eigen::Vector3d v = Eigen::Vector3d::Random();
    qx[i] = q[0]; qy[i] = q[1]; qz[i] = q[2]; qw[i] = q[3];
    x[i] = v[0]; y[i] = v[1]; z[i] = v[2];
  }

  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for(size_t head = 0; head < N; head += n_batch){
    quat_mult_vec(qx + head, qy + head, qz + head, qw + head, x + head, y + head, z + head, output_x + head, output_y + head, output_z + head);
  }
  auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << "Time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() << " us" << std::endl;

  double sum = 0;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    sum += output_x[i] + output_y[i] + output_z[i];
  }
  std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl;
}

Also note that the implementation basically compute the matrix element of the below in batch, then multiply it the vector also in batch
https://i.sstatic.net/0500x.jpg

To know why performance difference is so low you need to profile your code. In the end the performance you get is not always how fast you can compute things but also how fast you can get data to the processor. Sometimes it's cache misses, sometimes its missed branch predictions.  So get a profiler and measure the whole system and see if you can identify the biggest bottleneck

Try running it with Intel's VTune and see where the hotspots are. Unless you do them two at a time I'd tend to expect AVX2 with 4x 64 bit reals to have the edge here AOTBE.

Also, you would need to run each of the different builds at least 50-100 times and take an average to get a reasonable measure of what the actual differences are. Any single run will depend on what your OS is also doing at the moment and what all is in the processor pipeline. I see as much as a 3815 uSec (3+ %) difference in successive runs.

@DavidC.Rankin Update: I did experiment with smaller array size (40) and increase "outer iteration" to make the benchmark stable, found that AVX is two times faster than SSE. However, AVX512 is still the same or slightl better performance as AVX

This is expected on a Zen4 CPU as explained by Soonts. Zen4 uses double-pumping for AVX-512 so AVX-512 does not have a higher throughput. The new AMD Zen5 architecture does. AVX-512 can still be interesting on Zen4 in many cases: more available registers, new advanced instructions, masking, broadcasting, etc.

I think your long test with 10M inputs bottlenecks on memory bandwidth. 10M quaternions + 10M 3D vectors take 560 MB RAM in FP64 precision, while your CPU only has 16MB L3 cache.
The reason why for short test AVX512 is close to AVX2 is probably CPU microarchitecture. According to uops.info, on Zen 4 CPUs the throughput of vector addition and multiplication is twice as fast with 32 bytes AVX vectors compared to 64 bytes AVX512 vectors.
Couple possible micro-optimizations in your code.
You can compute v * 2.0 as v + v, this gets rid of the 2.0 constant vector.
For AVX and AVX512 targets, you can compute ( a * b ) + ( c * d ) + ( e * f ) expression as fma( e, f,  fma( c, d, a * b ) ) this reduces count of instructions for that expression from 5 to 3, by 40%.

Yes, Zen 4 has 256-bit wide SIMD units.  512-bit uops can be useful to avoid front-end bottlenecks and get more out-of-order scheduling since each 512-bit uop takes 2 cycles in the SIMD ALU, so the same scheduler size holds twice as much work.  But the theoretical max FLOPs is the same for AVX+FMA or for AVX-512 on Zen 4, unlike Intel or Zen 5.
